# Uncaught JQuery TypeError with Plugin on Wordpress Site (site in post)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Working on a side-project here: http://beta.bookvideoclub.com/
I'm using the UserPro plugin, and there are multiple JQuery errors that popup.

*Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).smartresize is not a function*

*Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).chosen is not a function*

If you click the Login button on the top right, multiple Jquery errors appear in the Register process. Additionally the checkbox does not work at the very bottom.

Thanks in advance if you know and can assist in coming up with the solution to this puzzle.

Comment: have you included the libraries for those plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you use at least 2 jQuery libraries on the page.
Check this screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxl8Z.png

`smartresize` was added to 1.11.2, but you use it in 1.10.2

Here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFCE1.png It is a list of added scripts on the page. You add 1.11, then execute JS with your method and after that jQuery is rewrited by 1.10

Comment: Anarion - I just removed the conflicting 1.10.2 script from the end of the body. The same error still seems to occur.

Comment: Are updates on the site? You might have even more jQueries :) Try `jQuery.fn.jquery` in console to find out the latest add one.

Comment: i'm having trouble finding why the jquery is still being inserted. do you have skype or PM? :)

Comment: Hi Eddiewang, great to hear. I hope my answer helped you :) CMS's are awful because every plugin wants to add all his dependency scripts. As a result they all conflict

Comment: Eddiewang,  What was your fix? Perhaps others such as myself would benefit from understanding how you fixed the problem.